# Double Relationship in SQLalchemy

Tags: database, insert, sqlalchemy, relationship

I got following problem in sqlalchemy. I made three different tables in sqlite, the first has no realtion, the second has a relation to the first and the third a relation to the second. So when I want to insert things in the first and the second table everything works fine. When I want to insert datas in the third table I'm getting troubles when I'm going to do it like it's discribed in the [tutorial](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/tutorial.html#working-with-related-objects). Here is my code for the three tables:

First table:

```
# Save_Data_Type.py

from sqlalchemy import ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy import Column, Float, Integer, String
from base import Base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, backref

########################################################################
class Save_Data_Type(Base):

__tablename__ = "save_datas_type"

save_datas_type_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
type_memory = Column(String)
comment = Column(String) 
dummy1 = Column(String)
dummy2 = Column(String) 
#----------------------------------------------------------------------
def __init__(self, type_memory, comment, dummy1, dummy2):
    """"""
    self.type_memory = type_memory
    self.comment = comment
    self.dummy1 = dummy1
    self.dummy2 = dummy2
```

Second Table

```
# Save_Data.py
from sqlalchemy import ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy import Column, Float, Integer, String
from base import Base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, backref


########################################################################
class Save_Data(Base):
""""""
__tablename__ = "save_datas"

save_datas_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

save_datas_type_id  = Column(Integer,ForeignKey("save_datas_type.save_datas_type_id"))
save_datas_type = relationship("Save_Data_Type", backref=backref("save_datas", order_by=save_datas_id))

value = Column(Float)

comment = Column(String)

dummy1 = Column(String)


#----------------------------------------------------------------------
def __init__(self, value, comment, dummy1):
    """"""
    self.value = value
    self.comment = comment
    self.dummy1 = dummy1
```

Third Table

```
# Station.py
from sqlalchemy import ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, Boolean, String
from base import Base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, backref


########################################################################
class Station(Base):
""""""
__tablename__ = "stations"

stations_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
name = Column(String)  
password = Column(String) 

save_datas_id = Column(Integer,ForeignKey("save_datas.save_datas_id"))
save_datas = relationship("Save_Data", backref=backref("stations", order_by=stations_id))


dummy1 = Column(String)
dummy2 = Column(String)
dummy3 = Column(String)


#----------------------------------------------------------------------
def __init__(self, name, password, dummy1, dummy2, dummy3):
    """"""
    self.name = name     
    self.password = password
    self.dummy1 = dummy1
    self.dummy2 = dummy2
    self.dummy3 = dummy3
```

base.py

```
# base.py

from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
Base = declarative_base()
```

So if I'm going to insert the datas like that:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

import base

from Save_Data_Type import Save_Data_Type
from Save_Data import Save_Data
from Station import Station

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///Database.db', echo=True)

base.Base.metadata.create_all(engine, checkfirst=True)

# create a Session
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()


jack = Save_Data_Type("Ring Memory",'In seconds',None,None)
jack.save_datas = [Save_Data(1980,'Sometimes more, sometimes less',None)]
jack.save_datas.stations = [Station('name1','123456',None,None,None)]

session.add(jack)

session.commit()
```

Nothing is writing in the the third table of the database. How is the usual way to build this relationship?

Thanks in advance,

Johannes

Comment: Or is it better to delete all relationships and add the ForeignKey manual by query to the table?

Comment: your example has two classes named "Save_Data", is one supposed to be named "Save_Data_Type"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from some typos in the code you posted (see comment from zzzeek), it looks like the problem will be solved by replacing the code:

```
jack.save_datas.stations = [Station('name1','123456',None,None,None)]
```

with the one below:

```
jack.save_datas[0].stations = [Station('name1','123456',None,None,None)]
```

The reason is the following: in your case you assign/create a `stations` attribute to a class member. Not only this does not do the right job, it might actualy harm your ORM model. 
In the second case you *correctly* assign the `Station` instance to the first `save_datas`.
The more clear code would look like this:

```
jack = Save_Data_Type("Ring Memory",'In seconds',None,None)

save_data1 = Save_Data(1980,'Sometimes more, sometimes less',None)
jack.save_datas.append(save_data1)
# or: jack.save_datas = [save_data1]
# or (my favourite): save_data1.Save_Data_Type = jack

save_data1.stations = [Station('name1','123456',None,None,None)]
# or... similar to the relationship above
```